# How can I put row into a string ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, try-catch

I'm trying to make a program where a teacher can give or change student's marks in csv file.

I figured out how to reach a column, but now I need to reach a row so that the program can ask what mark do you want to put for this criteria.

I want to put row into String Arraylist and then use it with `pattern.matches()` method, but I don't know how to do it.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is for my column code

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Path path = Paths.get("project.csv");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(lines.get(0).split(","));  //columns of csv
//get the rows in a list
List<List<String>> values = lines.stream()
        .skip(1).     //skip column
        .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: but teacher didnt teach list thing so that i cant use. Is there a another way with string arraylist and pattern.match ? thats what he said you can do with these

Answer (score 0):

What about creating new `array` and storing your data with modified values in the new array?

Something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] cols = line.split(",");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int subjectToGiveMark = in.nextInt(); // for creativity is 2
int mark = in.nextInt(); // which mark should be given 
final int size = cols.length; 
String[] finalResult = new String[size]; 
int index = 0;


while(index<finalResult.length ) {
    if (index==subjectToGiveMark) {
      finalResult[index]= String.valueOf(mark);
    } else {
    finalResult[index]=cols[index];
    }
    index++; 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you writed correct ? it gives error in in in.nextLine codes

Comment: Sorry, it should be of course `nextInt();`. Edited in my post! Have a look.

Comment: But then in the finalResult[index] = mark code mark gives error it says cannot convert from int to string

Comment: Edited, have a look now.